# How do crackers determine number of iterations of a Hashing algorithm?

Tags: hashing

Does a cracker need to know the number of iterations a hashing algorithm uses to compute a hash?

If they don't know it, how do they figure it out? How much longer does it take to figure it out, than if they didn't know?

I can only guess that they try a number of the most common passwords, and try it with different iterations, and see what amount of iterations returns the most correct passwords. Would this even work though?

Comment: I'm not a security expert, but it seems to me that a good security system should be difficult to defeat even if the algorithm is open-source.

Comment: this has most likely been already asked and answered at Security.SE - they've got [about 500 questions in the 'hash' tag](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash)

Comment: @gnat: Which one of those 500 answers this question? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you're curious, migrate and see how regulars will close it as a dupe there, possibly along with voting down for apparent lack of effort. [What is considered a reasonably high iteration count?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8125/what-is-considered-a-reasonably-high-iteration-count)

Answer (score 4):

The usual attack models assume that the attacker knows the exact algorithm used and the only unknown is (in the case of hashing-to-hide-plaintexts) the plaintext. In short, [the enemy already knows the system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).

Sometimes this gives the attacker too much credit, but that's better then underestimating them. Since password hashes are typically retrieved by breaking into a production server, it's likely that the application source code (which includes a full specification of the hashing procedure used) was grabbed at the same time. In other cases, the source code is open to begin with.

Comment: Even if the source code wasn't grabbed, the algorithm and iterations used to create a password hash will often be saved together with it in the database - this makes it easy to change hashing strategy without immediately recalculating all hashes.

Answer (score -4):

Unless you implement hashing algorithm on server side, and use some non-standard algorithm, Everything about hashing algorithm is known to hacker. if implemented on client side, it can be reverse engineered, even if you use non-standard algorithm, or obfuscate a standard algorithm.

Comment: A non-standard algorithm implemented on the server does *not* hinder an attacker. That belief is security through obscurity and the reasons it's bad are too numerous to list in a single answer let alone comment.

Comment: One of the most fundamental concepts behind security is to use algorithms that are just as effective even if they are known to the attacker.